# Can you give one direction for all columns in an order by?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

Is it possible to provide the direction once for all columns in an order by statement?

i.e.

```
select *
from my_table
order by name desc, type desc
```

can you write the same thing using "desc" once?

Maybe something similar to this?  (this doesn't work)

```
select *
from my_table
order by (name, type) desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The SQL standard doesn't allow that.

Having said that, there may be some RDBMS that do support a syntax like that. I'm just not aware of any.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `row_number` for that:

```
select  *
from    my_table
order by 
        row_number() over (order by name, type) DESC
```

The final DESC will invert the row_number's order.  So it'll flip ASC to DESC for both name and type.

Comment: While equivelent, I would not trust the query optimizer to recognize the trickyness and just do one sort, versus sorting once to generate row_number() and then again to sort the output in the other direction. I took a quick look at the explain plan for `order by row_number() over (order by A, B) DESC` verus `order by A desc, B desc` did have an extra step, a "WINDOW SORT". (EE 10.2.0.4.0 64 bit on linux)

Comment: I think it's easier to type ORDER BY name DESC, type DESC ;-)

Comment: @DCookie -- and also clearer for those having to maintain the code later